# How to Import Google workspace data automatically to Big Query database?

Tags: import, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, data-synchronization, database-link

How to daily import Google workspace data automatically to Big Query database?

I'm new to Big Query and i can do it manually but i want to automate this process. Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Google Workspace is a quite large sets of very different tools. Do you mean from Google Spreadsheets ?

Answer (score 0):

With BigQuery you can create `external tables`, that enable you to query data that is stored in your Google Drive (CSV, Avro, JSON, or Google Sheets documents).

You can find a nice how-to [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive).